# Android How make the same action bar?

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat, android-design-library

Please help me. How i can make the same action bar?(Without using the observablescrollview library)
http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsR1lZQUxtWFRFMEU/patterns-scrolling-techniques_standard_appbar_xhdpi_004.webm

Or same action bar as in PlayMarket app. I mean the same hiding and appearance on scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Design support library**.

Just add this dependency in your `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Then use something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`
will add a behavior to the view, which can be listened by the AppBarLayout to animate its children.

The `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` line will cause that the Toolbar will scroll of the screen when user scrolls down the list.

You can find more info in the [official blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).

Comment: Yes, and I've got is not exactly what is shown on video